# Be able to change the colour of seperate divs by clicking on buttons

Tags: php, jquery, html, layout, colors

I am creating a wedding checklist website.
For my checklist I want to enable the user to change the colour of the todo item to red, amber and green, red for not done, amber for partly done, and green for done. I was wndering how to achieve this, I would also like it to be saved to the database. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You'll need to provide code for what you did so far, especially since your request is pretty broad.

Comment: Knockout.js could achieve what I think you're asking for, binding css classes to model values from your database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in db

1. add a column `status` with a value of 1 or 2 numbers ( it'll be the id of a status)
2. Create a table `status` with a `status_id`, `status_title` ,`status_color`, `color_id`, `enabled`

in your code :

1. in your div , get the color of the task by getting the stored id

   `$colorOfTheTask = "SELECT color_id FROM status,task WHERE task.status = status.id ";`
2. Use this on each of your td (i suppose you're using tables)
   `<td <?php echo 'style="background-color:'.$color_id.';color:'.$color_id.'"';?></td>`

Like that you'll be able to manage your colours easier. You can still use a if statement like this :

```
<td <?php if($id_status==1){
          echo 'style="background-color:red;color:red';}
      if($id_status==2){
          echo 'style="background-color:green;color:green';}
      if($id_status==3){
          echo 'style="background-color:#amber-color-code;color:#amber-color-code"';} ?>
</td>
```

Answer (score 0):

are you looking for something like this?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(".button").click(function () {
            $("#colorPick").css("background-color", $(this).attr("value"));
        });
    });

</script>
<body>
   <div id="colorPick" style="width:100px;height:100px; "></div>
   <input type="button" class="button" value="Red" />
   <input type="button" class="button" value="Green" />

</body>
```