# Change background color dynamically

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, css

I have created website theme. In this I get confused on adding one feature to this. That is I want to change theme background color according to selected color values from user side. For example our table like this:

```
+------+------------------+---------+
| s_no |    attribute     |  color  |
+------+------------------+---------+
| 1    | background-color | #F6F4F0 |
+------+------------------+---------+
```

And now I want to set `CSS` property like this

```
body{
    background-color:"color value from table"
}
```

Is this possible? If possible, Kindly explain. Thanks for advance!.

Comment: Ofcourse it's possible, you have to convert your `.css` file to `.php` and fetch the records from your database and place it accordingly.

Comment: Take a look to this post , it's the same process :
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22148557/be-able-to-change-the-colour-of-seperate-divs-by-clicking-on-buttons/22149034#22149034

Comment: So best way is write inline css right?

Comment: or javascript/jquery... I wouldn't change main css file, but thats just like my opinion... :)

Comment: @OP the link posted by BKM is a pretty good resource, you should check it out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could have a look at this.

http://www.barelyfitz.com/projects/csscolor/

It clearly explains how to add `CSS` style dynamically.

You can do something like this in your PHP

```
<?php
header("Content-type: text/css");
$white = '#fff';
$dkgray = '#333';
$dkgreen = '#008400';
?>
body {
 background:<?=$white?>;
 color:<?=$dkgray?>;
}
h1, h2, h3, h4 {
 color:<?=$dkgreen?>;
}
blockquote {
 color:<?=$dkgreen?>;
}
```

Comment: -1: While the linked resource looks good. Link only answers on SO are not good. The link may break and your answer becomes useless. If you only want to provide a link then you should do so as a comment. Alternatively, edit your answer to include key extracts from the link that would be useful on their own, if the link was not available

Comment: @musefan Updated my answer with some steps. Even if the link brokes this might helps some one

Answer (score 1):

You can use `PHP` in `Styles` like

```
body{
    background-color:<?php echo $color;?>
}
```

And while getting the `$color` each time use `RAND()` function.

Comment: No, he wants option selected by user.

Comment: But he didnt mentioned from where user can select..So I thought it from DB

Comment: Yes, you are right, i am not sure now, too (btw, didn't down voted your answer, i don't do it:)) However, colors are in table, but, first, user should make selection, so RAND() will not be option, i guess... :)

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
setcookie("bgcolor", "#f2f2f2", time()+3600);
?>

<?php
if (isset($_COOKIE["user"]))

echo "<style>body{background-color:" . $_COOKIE["bgcolor"] . "}</style>";

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this javascript function....

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function changeBG(color)
{
var body=document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
body.style.background= color;
}
</script>
```

and fire this  function on button click or any event you want like..

```
<input type="button" onclick="return changeBG(this.value);" value="<?php echo $color; ?>">
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of write PHP in your CSS you can use javascript (ajax request). I have not enough information about what you want to do but you can retrieve data by using AJAX when the user choose a value in the select. It's more complex to develop but write PHP code into CSS... Isn't dirty ? Maybe I'm wrong on this point.