# change colour of item according to status in php

Tags: javascript, php, css, database, status

I am a newbie to this. I am creating a website whereby the user can input information into a todo list.  I got a plugin for the todo list which is done in javascript and is connected to my database, but I want the user to be able to change the status of the todo item, so there would be a button saying done, partially done, and not done.  When they click on this the todo item, it would change colour to signify done, not done, or partially done. I have inputed a `status` row into my todo table in the database, but I am unsure of the code on how to make this happen.

Inside my todolist table in my database there is `id`, `content` and now `status`. 
Thanks in advance

```
todo.addList = function (text){
$.ajax({
    url: 'server.php',
    method: 'GET',
    data: 'op=addList&content='+text,
    dataType: "json", // response as json
    error: function(res){
        todo.updateInfo("Failed to add new entry");
    },
    success: function(res){
        todo.updateInfo("New Entry added");
        todo.addView(res);
    }
});
```

This is the code that 'gets' the information from the server

Comment: Please show some sample code you wrote and where you got stuck. Otherwise the answers will be very ethereal.

Comment: If you want to change things "browser side" you don't want to use php - use javascript instead. Does clicking the todo item generate a call to the server?

Comment: Please don't put code in a comment. Just edit your question and add the code in there.

Comment: sorry, i have edited the question

Answer (score 0):

And store the status in a DB :

1- add a column `status_id` with a value of 1 or 2 numbers ( it'll be the id of a status)

> I have inputed a status row into my todo table in the database

So add you collumn in this todo table

2- Create a table status with a `status_id, status_title ,status_color, color_id, enabled`

Take a look from this :
[Be able to change the colour of seperate divs by clicking on buttons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22148557/be-able-to-change-the-colour-of-seperate-divs-by-clicking-on-buttons/22149034#22149034)

// EDIT TO BE CLEAR :
At the end you'll have something like that :

```
// mysql query wich get all todo
$res=mysql_query("SELECT todo_name,todo_status FROM todo,status WHERE todo.status = status.id
// loop wich write all todo in the html table
while($tab=mysql_fetch_array($res))
{
    echo "<tr> <td>".$name."<td";
      if($id_status==1){
          echo 'style="background-color:red;color:red';}
      if($id_status==2){
          echo 'style="background-color:green;color:green';}
      if($id_status==3){
          echo 'style="background-color:#something;color:#something"';} 
    echo "</td>";
}
```

Comment: Sorry, for Number "1. add a column status_id with a value of 1 or 2 numbers ( it'll be the id of a status)" Where exactly am i adding this column? I am very new to this.

Comment: do yourself a favour and use css classes for this.

Comment: Oh yes i see now, so how do i then input dunttons with the value of done, partially done and not done, for them then to be connected to the status of 1,2 and 3?

Comment: When you table "status" is filled , you have just to get the id of the current status of your task , and  then apply css

Comment: I'm sorry I do not understand, i will have to do more research on this. I want buttons beside each todo item saying done, not done or partially done so the user can click them and they will change colour and also update the database.

Comment: Yes , that's why you're gonna need a loop to get all your task no ?
So , in your loop you get the name of the task, and his status

Comment: Ok, so after inputting the javascript code into my js file and creating the table in the database What code do i put into my php page

Comment: @user3298400 i've edited , it'll be more clear for you.